# How to delete second instance of same character and everything after

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with strings of alphanumeric text. The strings contain several “/” separators. I want to delete the second “/” and everything that follows it.

Examples:

```
text1inc4/4r_2/exte/ise24lsk/srcir5656we/kajsie/est3wt2w/1stbbd35werw.py#1  
(Desired result = “'text1inc4.4r_2”)

ex1text1/1.0.2.5/aud/algorithms/formulas/heaac/nov/exampleLib/dlb_example54lib/bs5acdeclib/int/all.h#5  
(Desired result = “'ex1text1.1.0.2.5”)
```

The below code deletes everything after the first “/” so I want to add some preceding code to replace the first “/” with a “.”. (I know several ways to do this with Excel formulas, but need to do it with VBA code instead.) The string length and content varies between the slashes.

```vb
For Each c In Range("Y2:Y" & LngLast)
    If InStr(c.Value, "/") Then
         c.Value = Left(c.Value, InStr(c.Value, "/") - 1)
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: You can use a formula for this - do you need VBA.

Comment: I know the Excel formulas to use but do need VBA in this case.  I was able to get the issue resolved though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `split` something along these lines

```
Dim s As String
Dim a() As String

s = "text1inc4/4r_2/exte/ise24lsk/srcir5656we/kajsie/est3wt2w/1stbbd35werw.py#1 "
a = Split(s, "/")
s = a(0) & "." & a(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nathan_Sav.  I was able to get help to resolve the issue by replacing: <c.Value = Left(c.Value, InStr(c.Value, "/") - 1)">  with this:    <c.Value = Replace(Left(c.Value, InStr(InStr(1, c.Value, "/") + 1, c.Value, "/") - 1), "/", ".")>  Thank you!